# how to apply bootstrap active class to an onclick

Tags: html, reactjs, redux

How do you apply a bootstrap class like `nav-link active` to a onlick(). I've been having hard time implementing this. I thought it would have just been as simple as.

```
 <a
       onClick={() => this.props.onUpdateSelectedProbe(probe)}
       className="dropdown-item nav-link active"
  >
```

But this however just makes all list items/anchor tags active.

```
return (
  <div style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>
    <ul className="nav nav-pills">
      <li className="nav-item dropdown ">
        <div
          className="dropdown-menu show"
          x-placement="bottom-start"
          style={{
            position: "relative",
            willChange: "transform",
            top: "5px",
            overflowY: "scroll",
            maxHeight: "200px"
          }}
        >
          {this.props.searchState.isActive === false
            ? probes.map(probe => (
                <a
                  onClick={() => this.props.onUpdateSelectedProbe(probe)}
                  className="dropdown-item"
                >
                  <div
                    className="dropdown-divider"
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}
                  ></div>
                  {probe.companyPN}: {probe.description}
                </a>
              ))
            : filteredProbes.map(filterprobe => (
                <a
                  onClick={() =>
                    this.props.onUpdateSelectedProbe(filterprobe)
                  }
                  className="dropdown-item"
                >
                  <div className="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  {filterprobe.companyPN}: {filterprobe.description}
                </a>
              ))}
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example of adding items to a list and conditionally showing a "selected" class

```css
.selected {
  background: red;
}
```

```js
function App() {
  const [people] = useState([
    { id: 0, name: "Mario" },
    { id: 1, name: "Luigi" },
    { id: 2, name: "Peach" }
  ]);

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});

  return (
    <div>
      {people.map(({ id, name }) => (
        <div
          className={selected[id] ? "selected" : ""}
          key={id}
          onClick={() => setSelected({ ...selected, [id]: true })}
        >
          {name}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-nobel-e6x6e